# Clean URL structure: /{id}/{slug} vs /{id}-{slug}

Tags: seo, clean-urls

I am making a url structure similar to that of Stack Exchange `webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/{id}/{slug}`, where no matter the slug you type there will be a `301` redirect to the correct slug as long as you got the right id. But I have found out that `/{id}-{slug}` could work the exact same way (the way I am programming at least), as in both cases the id is stripped from the url to present the right content.

So, is there any benefits doing this either way: `/{id}/{slug}` vs `/{id}-{slug}`? In the perspective of SEO, user experience, programming, etc.

Comment: User experience?  The shorter URL is better.

Comment: @Steve they will have the same amount of characters. The difference being a `-` and `/`.